# Efficient way of launching python script from exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, executable, popen

I know there's a lot of questions asking about the opposite, but is there a particularly good way to launch a Python script from an executable? The executable itself was originally written in Python and compiled using py2exe so I was thinking of using `popen()` and passing `python myscript.py` but not sure if that's the most efficient.

The particular script being launched would be Python 2.7 with the Python ArcGIS interpreter.

Comment: "An executable" basically means "a program." You're going to have to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: So, it's on Windows? That's still not very specific. Almost any program can be turned into a Windows-compatible executable. If you want a program to do something (like launching another program), you'll have to include those instructions within the program. Other than that, I'm still unsure of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to execute a python script externally, then just use `popen()` on your script, as you said.

Comment: Is that the best way? It needs to be interpreted as 2.7.

Comment: It'll be interpreted as your default python version

Comment: Even if the calling process wants to terminate as soon as it launches a new one, should `Popen()` be used over `call()`?

Comment: which language do you use to open the python script ?

Comment: A compiled python file is used to open a uncmopiled python file